# Change column name in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I've declared a class to create new table `Topics`:

```
Table["Topics"]
public class TopicViewModels
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I update the database successful and add some rows to the table. Now, I want to change column `Id` to `TopicId` without losing data, how can I do that?

I've tried: Right click table `Topics`, then click `Open Table Definition`, change the name `Id` to `TopicId` and update it.

That's okay. But the problem is: how to rename property `Id` in class `TopicViewModels` to `TopicId`?

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    string id = "";
    var topic = db.Topics.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    // what I want to achieve:

    string topicId = "";
    var _topic = db.Topics.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TopicId == topicId);

}
```

If I change to:

```
Table["Topics"]
public class TopicViewModels
{
    [Key]
    public string TopicId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

the data would be lost. That's similar to: delete column `Id` and add new column `TopicId`.

So, my question: how can I rename some property in class `TopicViewModels` without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Use ColumnAttribute `[Column("Id")]`